# String to Date conversion giving wrong date

Tags: java, date

I have string date:

```
"01/15/2015 12:00 AM"
```

and I want a date object  in `"dd/MM/yyyy' 'HH:mm:ss"` format. How can I achieve this?

I have tried:

```
String datetime1 ="01/15/2015 12:00 AM"
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm a");
Date datepicker1 = dateFormat.parse(datetime1);
```

But this `datepicker` is having a date in 2016. I don't know why this is happening.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change it to:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm a");
                                               ↑
```

You flipped `MM` and `dd`..

I guess that what happened here is that Java thought you have 15 months, added it to the day "1" in the year 2015, so you got 2016.. Your'e not far from implementing a time machine :)

Comment: Isn't it nice, how java chose *one* place in the world to be forgiving about formatting errors? :) I mean, it fails to parse" " 0 " into an integer, but happily chugs along with the 15th month :D

Comment: Thanx Maroun. It was a very silly mistake on my part.

Comment: @Dima Java designers thought about programmers who live in other galaxies that have different definition of time.

Comment: @MarounMaroun that should be taken care of by `locale`.

Comment: @Dima Well, this feature can be useful (but I'm to lazy to think about an use case :P). You can use [`#setLenient(false)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient%28boolean%29) to disable it.

Comment: @Tom, I know it can be useful. Just saying that parsing things like "0 " or "0.0" or "1,000" into a `Integer` is *way* more useful than that thing.